# Analogue match parent in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is there any analog of match parent in compose? How can I make the red and blue text the same height if the blue text is shorter? I want to ensure that the remaining part is filled with blue to the size of the red text.

```
@Composable
fun FilterPreview() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentHeight(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
    ) {
        Text(modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .background(Color.Red), text = "slfdsfkld77777777777777777777777777777777777777777777skfkdlsfkldskfkdlkfldskflkdlskflsdkflds")
        Text(modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .background(Color.Blue), text = "44444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444")
    }
}
```

I tried various combinations of `fillMaxSize`, `height(IntrinsicSize.Max)`, `height(IntrinsicSize.Min)`, etc.

[image: Вот что у меня получается]

Comment: Better way would be to add a view behind the text and fill it up with the required color! And make both the view of same height as max.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to keep all item's heights the same as the tallest child's height in a `Row`!

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.wrapContentHeight()
    .height(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Max) // *** important
    , horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
) {
    Text(modifier = Modifier
        .weight(1f)
        .fillMaxHeight() //*** important
        .background(Color.Red), text = "Compose\nis\ncool\n!!!")
    Text(modifier = Modifier
        .weight(1f)
        .fillMaxHeight() //*** important
        .background(Color.Blue), text = "I am a short text")
}
```

[image]